# How to select only 2 rows of same fruit type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

From the Table Below how to select only 2 rows of same fruit type?

```
id     fruitname      fruittype              
1      mango          organic                                         
2      apple          nonorgonic                 
3      mango          organic              
4      banana         organic           
5      mango          organic               
6      apple          nonorganic       




the output

id     fruitname      fruittype
1      mango          organic
2      apple          nonorganic
3      mango          organic
4      apple          nonorganic
```

here banana only once occured so not want
mango of organic 3 times occured so want 2 times only

Comment: Surely, 1,2,3,6 !!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.. Try this

```
 SELECT @a := @a + 1 as id, fruitname, fruittype
FROM  (SELECT @a := 0)  r JOIN (
SELECT fb1.fruitname,fb1.fruittype
    FROM testdb.fruit fb1
     GROUP by fb1.fruitname,fb1.fruittype
   HAVING count(fb1.fruitname) >=2
  UNION ALL
    SELECT fb1.fruitname,fb1.fruittype
      FROM testdb.fruit fb1
     GROUP by fb1.fruitname,fb1.fruittype
    HAVING count(fb1.fruitname) >=2) b
     ORDER BY fruitname,fruittype;
```

See if this is what u need.

Thanks

Comment: This is working fine but same row appears second time if i display id of table.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select * from fruit where fruittype ='organic' limit 2) UNION (select * from fruit where fruittype='nonorganic' limit 2);
```

May be joins help better.

Comment: if use this query banana would select if there in first record

Comment: what to do if I have n types of fruittype where n is 25?

Comment: What if there is another fruit with same fruittype??